# percentage along row of DataFrame pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame of dimension n x m. I would like to return a DataFrame of dimension n x m where each cell represents the percentage of the total along the row it exists.

For Example,

```
df=sc.parallelize([
    ('a1',15,2,0,3),
    ('a2',3,9,5,3),
    ('a2',4,10,4,2),
    ('a1',0,10,7,3)
]).toDF(['id1','x1','x2','x3','x4'])



    id1| x1| x2| x3| x4|

   | a1| 15|  2|  0|  3|
   | a2|  3|  9|  5|  3|
   | a2|  4| 10|  4|  2|
   | a1|  0| 10|  7|  3|
```

I would like to return

```
    id1|  x1|    x2|   x3|  x4|

   | a1| .75|   .1 |   .0| .15|
   | a2| .15|   .45|  .25| .15|
   | a2| .2 |   .5 |  .2 | .1 |
   | a1| .0 |   .5 |  .35| .15|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple. Compute sum per row:

```py
total = sum(df[c] for c in df.columns[1:])
```

and `select`:

```py
df.select(df.columns[0], *[(df[c] / total).alias(c) for c in df.columns[1:]])
```